# Solidity : Could not find artifacts for Migrations from any sources

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

I have an issue I tried to find solution [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91887/error-could-not-find-artifacts-for-migrations-from-any-sources) but not solved.

I create this truffle-config file :

```
require('babel-register')
require('babel-polyfill')

module.exports ={
    networks:{
        development:{
            host:'127.0.0.1',
            port:'7545',
            network_id:'*'
        },
        contracts_directory:'./src/contracts/',
        contracts_build_directory:'./src/truffle_abis/',
        compilers:{
            solc:{
                version :'^0.7.0',
                optimizer:{
                    enabled:true,
                    runs : 200
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the Migrations contract :

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0;
contract Migrations{
    address public owner;
    uint public last_completed_migration;
    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    modifier restrected() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    function setCompleted(uint completed)public restrected {
        last_completed_migration = completed;
    }
    function upgarde(address newAdress)public restrected {
        Migrations upgraded = Migrations(newAdress);
        upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);

    }
}
```

when I run migration `truffle migrate` I get error as mentioned in title of post.

the deploy script as named "1_initial_migration.sol' is like this :

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require('Migrations')
module.exports=function (deployer){
    deployer.deploy(Migrations)

}
```

I get this error as I said : `Error: Could not find artifacts for Migrations from any sources`

How can I solve this?

***Note : I use Ganashe network***

Answer (score 1):

Those keys about location of files, `contracts_directory` and `contracts_build_directory`, should be out of `networks`:

```
module.exports ={
    contracts_directory:'./src/contracts/',
    contracts_build_directory:'./src/truffle_abis/',
    networks:{
        development:{
            host:'127.0.0.1',
            port:'7545',
            network_id:'*'
        },
        compilers:{
            solc:{
                version :'^0.7.0',
                optimizer:{
                    enabled:true,
                    runs : 200
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```